# Web App: How to make Android Phones compress video before uploading?

Tags: php, javascript, android, html, web-applications

I am making a simple web application where users can upload media for everyone to view. My only problem is that the `iPhone` will always compress the video before it uploads it (saving my server from getting overencumbered too fast), but the `Android` does not. `Android` videos (`Nexus 4`) are taking >3 times as much disk space as my `iPhone` (`4`) videos, because the `iPhone` compresses the videos before uploading.

The web application is made in `.js` and `.php`.

Is it possible to force `Android` phones to compress videos before they upload them in any way? Perhaps transcode them on the server before storing it.

Comment: what file extensions are we talking about?

Comment: Android are using mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a video transcoding service :

You have two ways  :
— Use an existing API : (dmcloud | zencoder | pandastream...)
— Run an ffmpeg instance on your server.

Comment: Thanks, will look into those. I just found the subject hard to google since most search results on iphone/android transcoding are related to transcoding movies and TV series for tablets/phones, not the other way around which is what I am looking for.